# COUNT RESULT +++++++++++ in DB2?

Tags: sql, count, db2-400

How to count use SQL if the total record is 4155925081.
But result count is

> = ++++++++++++++

I used the SQL

```
select count(*) from table9;
```

Can anyone to help me to figure out why I am getting that result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`count_big()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000760.html):

```
select count_big(*)
from table9;
```